# How to Title Case a sentence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, indexing, element

```html
<html>
<head>
 <!--Wei Wu Section A-->
 <title>This is the 4th extra credit</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function toUpper(stringFromUser){
  var arrayOfStrings = [];
   arrayOfStrings = stringFromUser.split(" ");
   for(i=0;i<arrayOfStrings.length;i++){
    //if (char(arrayOfStrings[i][0]) <= 122 && char(arrayOfStrings[i][0]) >= 97){
      if (arrayOfStrings[i].charCodeAt(0) <=122 && arrayOfStrings[i].charCodeAt(0) >=97){ 
     arrayOfStrings[i] = arrayOfStrings[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arrayOfStrings[i].slice(1);
    }
   }
  var afterTitle = "";
  afterTitle = arrayOfStrings.join(" ");
   document.getElementById('afterChange').innerHTML = afterTitle;
  }

 </script>
 <p>Enter a sentence and I will turn it into Title Case!<input id="textInput" value=""></p>
 <button onclick="toUpper(textInput.value)">Change case!</button>
 <p id="afterChange"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi thank you in advance for all your help. this is one of the code that I was working on. the purpose of this code is to "Title Case" the first letter of each word in the sentence. My code runs quite well after some work.

But I have one question: On line 14, I was trying to directed assign the uppercase letter to arrayOfString[i][0], it didn't work. Instead, I changed the whole element, AKA the element in the array. Why didn't that work? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable - you cannot change individual characters in them by assigning to their `[]` indicies. So, you have to slice them apart and put them back together, as you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to Title Case

```html
<html>
<head>
 <!--Wei Wu Section A-->
 <title>This is the 4th extra credit</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function toUpper(stringFromUser){
    var afterTitle = toTitleCase(stringFromUser);
    document.getElementById('afterChange').innerHTML = afterTitle;
        }
        function toTitleCase(str)
        {
            return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
        }
 </script>
 <p>Enter a sentence and I will turn it into Title Case!<input id="textInput" value=""></p>
 <button onclick="toUpper(textInput.value)">Change case!</button>
 <p id="afterChange"></p>
</body>
</html>
```